# Getting database related information and more with PHP

Tags: php, statistics

I need some way to get some statistics for a website of mine.

Is there a way to grab this information via PHP:

- Database size - the size of the database where my website stores its
  information
- Database server - The name and version of the database type I am
  using (eg: MySQL 5.5.24-log)
- Memory usage

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- **Database size - the size of the database where my website stores its
  information**

  Try this to get the size in bytes:

  ```
  mysqli_select_db("yourdatabase");  
  $q = mysqli_query("SHOW TABLE STATUS");  
  $size = 0;  
  while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($q)) {  
      $size += $row["Data_length"] + $row["Index_length"];  
  }
  ```

  then to convert in megabytes:

  ```
  $decimals = 2;  
  $mbytes = number_format($size/(1024*1024),$decimals);
  ```
- **Database server - The name and version of the database
  type I am using (eg: MySQL 5.5.24-log)**

  I don't think you can.. You could be using multiple databases too (see #1). You can always get the current version using [`mysqli_stats`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.stat.php) or [`PDO::getAttribute`](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.getattribute.php), but you'd have to be connected to your database first (either MySQL, or Oracle or w.e.).
- **Memory usage**

  Use [`memory_get_usage`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.memory-get-usage.php)

Answer (score 1):

Please refer to the PHP documentation for the functions you can use

http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.stat.php

http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-stat.php

http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.getattribute.php